# sending http header "X-Auth-Token" with scala/java adds unwanted double-quotes

Tags: http, playframework-2.3, double-quotes

Edit: It was not this issue at all, but a json parser implementation.

Sending a request from postman (an http client for chrome) with this header, successfully arrives at the server. When I try the same http request from a scala/java client the "X-Auth-Token" header value appears a bit different.

when sent from postman:

```
X-Auth-Token => ArrayBuffer(eyJ0eXAiOiJK.......)
```

when sent from http java client:

```
X-Auth-Token => ArrayBuffer("eyJ0eXAiOiJK.......")
```

I am running a play-framework server and the request are part of test inside the server tests-code

I've used play.api.ws.WS, play.ws.WS and java.net.HttpURLConnection for client implementations.

Comment: Could you show us the code where you set the token value?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks wwkudu.

It was my bad (and the Json parseer). 
After getting a token I've parsed it using this line

```
val token = play.api.libs.json.Json.parse(res.getBody).\("token").toString()
```

(as I used to from Gson) Where I should have done this:

```
val token = play.api.libs.json.Json.parse(res.getBody).\("token").as[String]
```